# Testing Spring MVC POST with IntelliJ REST client causes 415

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm developing an application in Java/Spring MVC and have no problem with testing my GET methods. The problem occur then I try to test the POST using @RequestBody.

The error:

```
HTTP 415 The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.
```

I created a simple test to show my problem:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class ConcreteTestController implements TestController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    public void add(@RequestBody Dummy dummy) {
        System.out.println(dummy);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Override
    public Dummy get() {
        Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
        dummy.setName("apa");
        return dummy;
    }

}
```

The Dummy class is very simple:

```
public class Dummy {

    private String name;

    public Dummy() {}
    // Omitted setters and getters.
}
```

The jsonresponse from the GET looks like this:

```
{"name":"apa"}
```

I'm starting the IntelliJ REST client and using the json above as request body. I've tried using both application/json and */* under Accept in the header with no difference in result.

Any idea what could cause this? I'm stuck and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

By default you have to add Content-Type manually in the REST client in IntelliJ. I had forgotten to do so and to set it to application/json. After having done so it is working fine.